# Sample Sybase ASE 15.0.3 database

Tags: sql-server, sybase, sybase-ase, sybaseiq

We are trying to migrate a database from Sybase ASE Server 15.0.3 to SQL Server 2016 with the help of a migration assistant application. We tried doing this by creating sample databases in the Sybase Server and then migrating it to the SQL Server 2016 but we were unable to test for all the components due to lack of a proper database.

Let us know if there is anything that can be done for the following:

1. Where can we find real time databases or sample databases to work on?
2. What is the migration strategy to follow in this scenario?
3. Is there any reference for the steps involved in the migration process?

Comment: Have you considered using a copy of your own databases, perhaps starting with test databases, for migration testing?